# IBAction cycle through images on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to use an IBAction method that when on tap cycles through images. Ie one image and a button is shown unload and when the user taps the button a new image is shown in its place etc. Right now it just shows the first image in the array. When I tap the button a second time nothing happens. Can someone please help me edit this to cycle through all of my images? Thanks.

***EDIT***

```
//when i tap the button only the first image shows in the array. What should I edit from the current app?

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//Implementing our method
- (IBAction)buttonPressed

{
NSArray *imagesArray = @[@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png"];
count ++;

if(count == imagesArray.count)
{
    count = 0;
}

yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:count]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

add images into your project and store those images names into an `NSArray`

for ex.

```
//declare imagesArray as instance variable

NSArray *imagesArray = @[@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png"];
```

and in the button action method

```
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed 
 { 
          count ++;

          if(count == imagesArray.count)
          {
           count = 0;
          }

          yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:count]];
 }
```

Comment: if the answer is useful to you, accept answer, it makes others easy to find the correct one...:)

Comment: thanks for your code, do you have any edits to cycle through all the images instead of the just the first one. (i edited my question) Right now Im getting a compiler issue saying incompatible pointer to integer etc. Right now my .h has `NSInteger *count;` And it only cycles to the first image on tap and nothin after more than one tap. Any edits?

Comment: shouldn't we be cycling through the images in a slightly different way? did this code work for you?

Comment: you have to create count variable as "NSInteger count" not like this NSInteger *count; (pointer matters)